# sectioning and indexing uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dictionary

What would you suggest is the best plist layout for supplying an alphabetically actioned table view?

Comment: +1 can u explain by example as i would easy to understand???

Comment: I think you are on the right track. You could have an array with 26 entries, and each entry contains a pointer to the start of the respective word dictionary. So then you could use this to generate your section header, and the dictionary to populate the content below.

Comment: Sorry for the bother guys. I guess the easiest way to determine a solution is asking what plist layout people would use if wanting to alphabetically section words and then words to lead to a definition detail view. And then what would the code look like to use that to populate the table. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView provided section headers and indices for Reusable Table Cell, by setting the data source and the delegate for the UITableView.
In your DataSource class, you can implement the functions

```
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

to decide the number of sections and the cells. And you can define the following two functions to set header view for section.

```
tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

And these for footer view:

```
tableView:heightForFooterInSection:
tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
```

BTW, about the header and footer view of the whole table, use

```
tableview setHeaderView|setFooterView
```

Use the following if the header/footer is only a string:

```
tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
tableView:titleForFooterInSection:
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to structure your data so that the sections are evident. In JSON format, your data might look like:

```
[
  {
    "section_name": "First Section",
    "section_index_name": "A",
    "section_contents": [
      "First Row",
      "Second Row",
      ... etc.
    ]
  },
  ... etc.
]
```

The `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is the number of dictionaries in your top-level array. The `numberOfRowsInSection:` is the number of elements in the `"section_contents"` array for the section.

Use the `"section_name"` as your `titleForHeaderInSection:`. Compile an array of all the `"section_index_name"` values to return from `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` to create your index.